# Micrometer with Prometheus Pushgateway not sending the recent metrics

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer, prometheus-pushgateway

I have a Spring boot application based on `CommandLineRunner`, when it starts it does some calculations, sends the metrics to Prometheus and shuts down.

I am using [Prometheus Push Gateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/pushing/) with Micrometer, mainly based on this tutorial:
https://luramarchanjo.tech/2020/01/05/spring-boot-2.2-and-prometheus-pushgateway-with-micrometer.html

This works fine if I leave the application running however with my particular Spring boot application, it looses the metrics sent just before the shutdown.

I have had similar issue with CloudWatch however it was clear with the Registry implementation `CloudWatchMeterRegistry`, that it starts a thread in the background and it uses the property `cloudwatch.step` to schedule the dispatch of the collected metrics. I am struggling to see how `PrometheusMeterRegistry` is working and not sending the metrics before the application shutsdown.

I have tried to add `meterRegistry.close();` just before the shutdown, however it still has the same issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation resolved this by calling the `shutdown()` method on `PrometheusPushGatewayManager`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired
  PrometheusPushGatewayManager prometheusPushGatewayManager;

  @PreDestroy
  public void onExit() {
    System.out.println("Exiting..");
    prometheusPushGatewayManager.shutdown();
  }
  
  ...
```

And add following in the application.properties:

```
management.metrics.export.prometheus.pushgateway.shutdown-operation=PUSH
```